# Template design pattern - how to "share" implementations?

Tags: design-patterns, ooad

Working on a project so I'll try to generalize this.

Say I have an abstract class *A* with an abstract method *method()*.

There are 4 subclasses of *A*: *B*, *C*, *D*, and *E*, but *B* and *C* have the same exact implementation of *method()*, and *D* and *E* have the same exact implementation of *method()*. How can I organize the code in such a way that minimizes duplicate code?

Comment: Do you really need to use a template method? You can have two subclasses of A - one for each method. Then you can have B and C extend one, and D and E extend the other one. If you don't want more subclasses and can ditch the template method, you can go with a strategy pattern: a strategy for each method and then compose the classes with the corresponding strategy.

Answer (score 0):

put the common method in A or in a subclass of a. override the method in the cases where it is different.

Comment: if I put the method in A, what if there are multiple subclasses that have the same implementation, but are different than A's?

Comment: you can put them in Asub1 and Asub2 then subclass the one you want

Comment: should Asub1 and Asub2 be abstract too? (A is abstract)

Comment: either way. if the implementation of one of these is complete, the make it non abstract.